# Consuming pipl api in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, api, webforms

i am having trouble configuring this API
https://pipl.com/dev/

i have this code in page load event, but the problem is that it keep on loading the page once i click on "veiw page in browser".

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RunAsync().Wait();
}
static async Task RunAsync()
{
    SearchAPIRequest req = new SearchAPIRequest(email: "clark.kent@example.com");

    SearchAPIResponse resp = await req.SendAsync();
    Console.Out.WriteLine(resp.Image.GetThumbnailUrl(200, 100, true, true));
    Console.Out.WriteLine(resp.Name);
    Console.Out.WriteLine(resp.Education);
    Console.Out.WriteLine(resp.Username);
    Console.Out.WriteLine(resp.Address);

    var jobs = resp.Person.Jobs.Select(j => j.ToString());
    Console.Out.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", jobs));
    Console.Out.WriteLine();

    var relationships = resp.Person.Relationships.Select(r => r.Names[0]);
    Console.Out.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", relationships));

    Console.Out.WriteLine();

}
```

Am i missing some code ? or any thing else.. please guide.

PS: I have already installed their package with "PM> Install-Package piplclient"

Answer (score 0):

The ASPX page needs to have "Async=true" in order to use an async method. The following is an example backend C# file:

```
using Pipl.APIs.Search;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SearchAPIRequest request = new SearchAPIRequest(email: "clark.kent@example.com");
            try
            {

                var response = await request.SendAsync();
                Response.Write(response.Name.ToString());
            }

            catch (SearchAPIError ex)
            {

                Console.Out.WriteLine(e.ToString());

            }

            catch (IOException ex)
            {

                Console.Out.WriteLine(e.ToString());

            }
        }
    }
}
```